# NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm trying to style the default alert messages in ruby using bootstrap, and I ran into a pinch where I needed custom code but all I got was this

I am not able to find the issue here the server returns

---

```
Showing c:/users/aaron/jobonaut/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `full' for #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x3844458>
Extracted source (around line #4):
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

  <h2>Sign up</h2>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <!--<%= devise_error_messages! %> -->

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
```

Heres the code I have written so far

```
module DeviseHelper
        def devise_error_messages!
        return '' if resource.errors.empty?

        messages = resource.errors.full.messages.map {|msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
        sentence = I18n.t('errors.messages.not_saved', count: resource.errors.count, resource: resource.class.model.name.human.downo)

        html = <<-HTML
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4>#{sentence}</h4>
            #{messages}
        </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be simply `resource.errors.full_messages`